# Paypal disputes - how do I ensure I get my service deliverd or money back?

Tags: payment-terms

I paid a freelancer in full before he finished because he had some family problems. He has not delivered the website, he changed logins, took the website down and does not reply.

When in the resolutions centre you click "report a problem" but if I made 2 payments of 50% will i get all the money back. How exactly does it work? Will the refund me 100% if the freelancer does not deliver?

How can I ensure I'm covered if this gets escalated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about freelancing. I'd suggest you read the Paypal support pages or contact PayPal support if you have a question about their service.

Comment: I thought it was as its with a freelancer. I didnt find much info online and thought someone in the community could help with this.

Comment: This site is about *working* as a freelancer, not necessarily working *with* a freelancer - especially in terms of specific client-freelancer relationship issues. No one here knows what contract you may or may not have with the person you hired. This is, quite honestly, a PayPal support question. Chances of someone here being part of the PayPal support team are minimal at best.

Comment: As a relatively new member of this community I welcome the question in the light that I didn't know it's about "working as a freelancer, not necessarily working with a freelancer ".  On that note, I propose to someone with the appropriate rep to consider making it about freelancing in general.

Comment: @user6035379 if the site were designed to also encompass client questions about their relationship with a freelancer I feel it would add 2 very distinct differences to the site -- 1) You'd get complaints... accusations... rants from unhappy clients. and 2) The risk of both a client and a worker posting increases. Admittedly probably not a great deal, but I know I will respond differently if I think a client of mine may read what I post. This ultimately leads to less impactful answers for actual freelancers. Probably a better discussion for [meta](http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm a freelancer myself... I just thought this was a place with tons of freelancers - I know that at least 50% of my income is through PayPal. 

If it's not the correct place to ask something like this - by all means take it down. I'm a noob here. I'll probably stay a noob with comments like "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about freelancing."

Comment: So if anyone finds this usefull;

When making a dispute, make sure you keep all the chats in Paypal (i made the mistake of replying through email) then he escalated it to a manual review. I did not get a chance to plead my case or upload files

I took a few screengrabs of conversations and pasted links to them. I also did not fill in the URL where I bought the service as the conversation/agreement happened on skype - this will count against me.

Last thing - before you submit your comment or reply copy and save it somewhere, Paypal Timeout function lost my text 3 times before submitting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about Freelancing as described in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about freelancing per what's in the Help Center.

Comment: Paypal has all kinds of methods for disputes, refunds, insurance, etc. You can look at their web site and get the information you need there.

Comment: I believe posts such as this are on topic, agreed, the discussion would be suitable as a meta post rather than within the comments of each question from people working with freelancers. Similar sites such as the Workplace SE take questions from all, including those looking for work and hiring managers. a Stack exchange site should encompass an industry or subject as a whole, not just one perspective / job role from it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to contact Paypal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about freelancing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not freelancing

Answer (score 1):

If you meant on [freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com), you've broken the rule, as all payments are supposed to remain onsite *(on Freelancer.com)*.

As such, they *(Freelancer.com)* **CANNOT** intervene on your behalf.

If I were you, I'll rather consider it a lost battle; you can only get your money and/or the service paid for if and only if the freelancer in question chose to.

You may try consulting their support, but I truly doubt it will yield any results.

Otherwise, *PayPal* itself, but again, that will depend on many factors; in this case: I think the earlier, the better.

Comment: Its not with freelancer.  I've been working with him on and off for the last year. This is the first time something like this has happened. I've read everything there is on Paypal about this but they dont give too much info.

Comment: ***Call*** PayPal, if there's anything that can be done, you will find out by speaking to a real person - as you've noticed, PayPal's documentation is "less than complete" and very often "less than helpful"